# Delphi Indy: cannot load SSL libraries first time. A retry works

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

I'm using the latest indy snapshot (installed yesterday) and newest SSL libraries.

When trying to send a mail using idSMTP, the first time the component connects, I get an exception:

> Could't load the SSL libraries

. Funny thing is, a retry works always. Debugging I found that the problem is in IsSSLOpenSSLHeader, function Loaad: boolean, line

```
@OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms := LoadFunctionCLib('OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms');
```

Why does it fail the first time and not the second is still a mystery to me, but before I go on investigating I would like to as if anybody knows the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you are using is NOT the latest snapshot.  That bug was fixed a couple of weeks ago.  The line you quote is NOT in the latest code, it has been replaced with the following:

```
fn_OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf = 'OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf';
fn_OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms = 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms';

@OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms := LoadOldCLib(fn_OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms, fn_OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Delphi XE-1 on Win 7/64, with the SSL and Indy that are installed by default. This week I had to do some work with SMTP and SSL, and I ran into the same problem you reported. Our application is somewhat complex and is already live and deployed in several locations and it uses Indy at several points in the code, so installing a newer version of Indy and rebuilding etc, was not very palatable.

Since the problem only arises on the first pass, I traced through some of the code and came up with this simple, painless workaround:

```
            smtpClient.connect;
            smtpClient.disconnect;
            smtpClient.connect;
            if not smtpClient.Authenticate then
                raise ... 
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

Once you call `connnect` and then `disconnect`, the SSL libraries are loaded, so on your second call to `connect` you're good to go.

Works fine.